# js scrollIntoView is not smooth and doesn't work

Tags: javascript, events, view, scroll, smoothing

Hi I need help with smooth scrolling into that view or is there another method to do it better?

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        const pack = document.querySelector('#packagingTitle');
        let targetElement = evt.target; // clicked element
        do {
            if (targetElement == pack) {
                // This is a click inside. Do nothing, just return.
                evt.preventDefault();
                pack.classList.toggle('activeCat');
                pack.classList.toggle('backgroundLight');
                document.querySelector('#packagingSection').classList.toggle('hidden');
                pack.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
                return;
            }
            // Go up the DOM
            targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
        } while (targetElement);
        // This is a click outside.
        document.querySelector('#packagingSection').classList.add("hidden");
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, how can you click in the element if it was not in view?

Comment: Hello, the #packaginTitle is in view, not the #packagingSection

Comment: your are scrollingIntoView of pack (that is the #packagingTitle) and not the #packagingSection (try document.querySelector('#packagingSection').scrollIntoView(...) ?)